# understanding python strings and "raw_input()"

Tags: python, string, raw-input

I'm sure this is kind of silly but I'm having trouble understanding strings, and the raw_input object.

So, example

```
print "How much money do I have?",
checking balance = raw_input()
savings balance = raw_input()
print "I have %r and %r in my accounts." % (1000, 10000)
```

So, I have a very basic understanding of strings, but I don't really understand what's going on here. The raw input is just displaying a string of data that I define elsewhere in the program? and The "%r" just displays this? I don't understand how it's different from me using %s and defining my numbers there. I'm just very confused! Any explanation would help me.

Comment: There are several problems: variable names (`checking balance`, `saving balance`) must not contain spaces; you are not using them anywhere else.  The difference between `%r` and `%s` is that the former casts the element to a string with `repr()` while the latter uses `str()`.

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't display anything (especially not data defined elsewhere); it reads in a string entered by the user, and the program can do whatever it wants with this string, including displaying it if it so chooses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what each line in your program does:

1. `print` out a message;
2. `SyntaxError` (due to space in variable name);
3. `SyntaxError` (ditto); and
4. `print` two numbers unrelated to the `raw_input` you just tried to take.

Instead, you need something like:

```
print "How much money do I have?",
checking_balance = float(raw_input())
savings_balance = float(raw_input())
print "I have %.2f and %.2f in my accounts." % (checking_balance, savings_balance)
```

What *this* does:

1. `print` again
2. Take input, convert to `float`, and store as `checking_balance`;
3. As above, with `savings_balance`; and
4. `print` the numbers you just inputted, formatted to two decimal places.

(*Note*: more modern Python would make the last line:

```
print("I have {0:.2f} and {1:.2f} in my accounts.".format(checking_balance, savings_balance))
```

)

Comment: Yeah, I messed it up, I'm very new to python. Thank you all for clearing that up, I think I understand now